# No post data in ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

im having problems with an ajax request. the function is to increment/decrement items in a shopping cart. When the increment event is fire the post array comes up empty when printed.

Firebug shows the params being sent in the post request but in the controller nothing arrives.

The solution implemented is a bit scruffy but this is the way it has to be. The jquery is a non anonymous method outside the document.ready signature which could well be a contributor to the issue.

here's what I have...

jQuery

```
    function increment_item($ciid){     
    $("#processing").fadeIn("fast");
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=BASE_URL?>landing/inc_cart_item",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {id:$ciid,},
        success: function(data){
            $("#processing").fadeOut("fast");
            if(data.error) {
                alert(data.error);
            } else {
               // parent.$('#line1').text(data.line1);
                //parent.$('#line2').text(data.line2);
                //parent.$('#address-dialog').dialog('close');
                alert(data.line1);
            }
        }
    });
    //return false;           
};
```

The trigger in the view...

```
<a href="#" onClick="increment_item(<?=$item['cart_item_id']?>)" class="qty-inc-button" >More</a>
```

The controller method...

```
    function inc_cart_item(){

    $return_val = $this->cart_model->increment_cart_item($this->session->userdata('cart_id'),$this->input->post('id'));

}
```

EDITED TO ADD GENERATED SOURCE...

The table data

```
            </thead>
                    <tbody id="item_2823">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://localhost/cdn/images/112/7/thumb_lemberger2010.jpg">
                                                <p style="color: #666;">Bader</p>
                                            <p style="font-size: 16px;">Stettener Lindhälder Lemberger</p>
                    <a href="#" onclick="remove_item(2823)" id="remove-item-button" class="remove-item-button">Remove this item</a>
                </td>
                <td class="align-td-center">
                    8.20€                    </td>
                <td class="align-td-center">
                    <a href="#" onclick="increment_item(2823)" id="qty-inc-button" class="qty-inc-button">More</a>
                        1                        <a href="#" onclick="decrement_item(2823)" id="qty-dec-button" class="qty-dec-button">Less</a>
                    <input id="item_id" class="item_id" value="2823" type="hidden">
                </td>
                <td class="align-td-center">
                    <span id="value-shipping-2823">8.20€</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
                                <tbody id="item_2824">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://localhost/***/cdn/images/112/5/thumb_kerfttropfle2010.jpg">
                                                <p style="color: #666;">Bader</p>
                                            <p style="font-size: 16px;">Kerftströpfle</p>
                    <a href="#" onclick="remove_item(2824)" id="remove-item-button" class="remove-item-button">Remove this item</a>
                </td>
                <td class="align-td-center">
                    5.10€                    </td>
                <td class="align-td-center">
                    <a href="#" onclick="increment_item(2824)" id="qty-inc-button" class="qty-inc-button">More</a>
                        1                        <a href="#" onclick="decrement_item(2824)" id="qty-dec-button" class="qty-dec-button">Less</a>
                    <input id="item_id" class="item_id" value="2824" type="hidden">
                </td>
                <td class="align-td-center">
                    <span id="value-shipping-2824">5.10€</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Generated jquery

```
function increment_item($ciid){     
    $("#processing").fadeIn("fast");
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/***/***/landing/inc_cart_item",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {id:$ciid},
        success: function(data){
            $("#processing").fadeOut("fast");
            if(data.error) {
                alert(data.error);
            } else {
               // parent.$('#line1').text(data.line1);
                //parent.$('#line2').text(data.line2);
                //parent.$('#address-dialog').dialog('close');
                alert(data.line1);
            }
        }
    });           
};
```

Again the jQuery function im trying to use here is outside all the other generated jQuery in the     $(document).ready(function() { code block, i dont know if this could be the cause.

I've been wrestling with it a little while now, all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: open up chrome inspect element -> hit network tab and see what is going on ;)

Comment: This is the confusing bit, firebug says the params are there. under network tab its definitely there....but     print_r($_POST) from the controller produces an empty array hence nothing is passed to the model. the things I know look fine

Comment: can you try to write POST with UpperCase letters?
`type:"POST",`
Simply in one framework i have problem with LowerCase "post"

Comment: Don't show us the PHP that generates that HTML that contains the JavaScript that calls the function. Show us the code the browser actually gets.

Comment: caps don't make a difference, we use lower everywhere else on the app. thanks though. @Quentin, is a view source good enough?

Comment: @PeterDonoghue — Yes. View source shows the code that the browser gets (although a DOM inspector might munge it, so don't use one of those for this).

Comment: how many js libraries you have use in this script?

Comment: Edited to add generated code. Noquox at this point there 6 libraries loaded but I dont have any issues with anything else.

Comment: @PeterDonoghue you can try to use `jQuery` instead `$` - sometimes libraries has conflicts in script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the data is being posted correctly?  You have a comma inside your data json.

Also you could try:

```
   data: JSON.stringify({id:$ciid})
```

Comment: The trailing comma is only an issue in IE.  Plus he's not (and shouldn't be) sending JSON in the request.  He's trying to send "normal" POST data, which he seems to be doing correctly.

Comment: Ah! My mistake. I forgot dataType is the response type not request.